# Is it possible to duplicate a map record if needed?

Tags: reactjs, lodash

In my react project, I am using Lodash map to loop through records.

```
const products = [
  {name: "Apple", description: "A cool apple", qty: 1},
  {name: "Water", descirption: "Some watery water", qty: 3},
]

{map(products, (item, index) => {
  return (
    <tr>{item.name}</tr>
    <tr>{item.description}</tr>
  )
})
```

I want to list items separately if qty > 1.

In this above example I would like to return something like:

```
Apple | A cool apple
Water | Some watery water
Water | Some watery water
Water | Some watery water
```

I seemed to find something that is the reverse of what I need `_.uniq(array)` but cannot find the solution for my use case.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you use lodash and no the native map function of js?

Comment: To be completely honest, it was suggested to me when I started learning. I am not against using the native map function. Does this make things easier?

Comment: Regarding to the lodash documentation _Lodash makes JavaScript easier by taking the hassle out of working with arrays, numbers, objects, strings, etc_. It is more related to form instead of functionality I mean both do the same. From my perspective I prefer to use native code and I can do it easier with native code but depending of the perspective :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) to generate the number of items according to the `qty` property, and use [`Array.flatMap()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) (or lodash's [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap)) to convert the results to a single array:

```js
const Demo = ({ products }) => (
  <table>
  {
    products.flatMap((item, index) =>
      Array.from({ length: item.qty }, () =>(
        <tr>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
          <td>{item.description}</td>
        </tr>
      )))
  }
  </table>
)

const products = [
  {name: "Apple", description: "A cool apple", qty: 1},
  {name: "Water", description: "Some watery water", qty: 3},
]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo products={products} />,
  root
)
```

```css
td + td {
  padding-left: 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

If you want to use only lodash, you can replace `Array.from()` with [`_.times()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#times), and use [`_.flatMap()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#flatMap):

```js
const { flatMap, times } = _

const Demo = ({ products }) => (
  <table>
  {
    flatMap(products, (item, index) =>
      times(item.qty, () =>(
        <tr>
          <td>{item.name}</td>
          <td>{item.description}</td>
        </tr>
      )))
  }
  </table>
)

const products = [
  {name: "Apple", description: "A cool apple", qty: 1},
  {name: "Water", description: "Some watery water", qty: 3},
]

ReactDOM.render(
  <Demo products={products} />,
  root
)
```

```css
td + td {
  padding-left: 3px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use flatMap (native or Lodash's) with Array.from or Lodash's range()

```
const products = [
  {name: "Apple", description: "A cool apple", qty: 1},
  {name: "Water", description: "Some watery water", qty: 3},
]

products.flatMap(product => Array.from({length: product.qty}, () => product));
// result: 
// [{name: "Apple", description: "A cool apple", qty: 1},
//  {name: "Water", description: "Some watery water", qty: 3},
//  {name: "Water", description: "Some watery water", qty: 3},
//  {name: "Water", description: "Some watery water", qty: 3}]

products.flatMap(({qty, name, description}) => Array.from({length: qty}, () => ({name, description})));
// result: 
// [{name: "Apple", description: "A cool apple"},
//  {name: "Water", description: "Some watery water"},
//  {name: "Water", description: "Some watery water"},
//  {name: "Water", description: "Some watery water"}]

products.flatMap(({qty, name, description}) => range(0, qty).map(() => ({name, description})));
// result: 
// [{name: "Apple", description: "A cool apple"},
//  {name: "Water", description: "Some watery water"},
//  {name: "Water", description: "Some watery water"},
//  {name: "Water", description: "Some watery water"}]
```